# Keystrokes in node js enter key send

Tags: javascript, sockets

What I want to do is be able to click ENTER to send a message instead of manually sending a message.
Here is a bit of my code:

```
function Send(){
  if (delay && messageInput.value.replace(/\s/g, "") != ""){
    delay = false;
    setTimeout(delayReset, 1000);
    socket.emit("send", messageInput.value);
    messageInput.value = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Eloni and welcome to Stack Overflow. What problem have you encountered? Showing the HTML involved, and explaining what "click ENTER" means, may help getting answered.

Comment: ok so i mean if you hit enter on your computer you can send the message. because atm you nede to manually click send also thanks